# TailwindCSS arbitrary value in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

In a Rails 7 app with TailwindCSS (with the `tailwindcss-rails` gem), I have the `car` model with the `color` attribute stored as hexadecimal colors (i.e. `#a565cc`).

According to [TailwindCSS documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#arbitrary-values), it's possible to define an arbitrary value notation to generate a class for that color on-demand (i.e. `<button class="bg-[#1da1f2] ...">...</button>`).

So, I have added in my view `bg-[<%= car.color %>]`, which in Firefox inspector renders correctly,

[image]

But in the browser, the button doesn't have a background.

My Tailwind config looks like

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/assets/images/*.svg',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,html}'
  ]
 ...
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute instead, like:

```html
<button class="…" style="background-color: <%= car.color %>">
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, that's what I'm using right now. Thanks